# Paint a more thick edge of each n cells in a nattable and set a color

Tags: java, nattable

a) How to paint a more thick edge of each two cells horizontally?
b) and each 2 or 3 cell vertically?
c) how can i set the borders color ?

Thanks in advance.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EJRA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render a border only one one side of a cell you need to configure the `CustomLineBorderDecorator` around your content painter. Additionally you need to apply a special label to the cells that should show such a border, that indicates which borders to paint. These labels are defined in `CustomLineBorderDecorator` itself.

The color of the border can either be set statically on creating the `CustomLineBorderDecorator` or dynamically via style attributes.

To have this only for specific columns and rows use labels. This is explained in our [Getting Started Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html) or our [Styling documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=styling).

The NatTable project provides an Example Application that gives various examples for all the configuration possibilities and features supported. The requested feature is for example shown in `_4222_CellPainterExample`

Comment: Is it possible to paint two sides of a cell with different thickness?

Comment: Not by default. If you have such a special requirement you can still implement your own painter that supports such a feature. The NatTable framework is quite extensible.